# Как разрешить изменение размеров окна в PyQt6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt6, qmainwindow

Я делаю приложение на *PyQt6* и для запрета изменения размеров окна я использую метод `setFixedSize`, но сейчас мне надо разрешить это самое изменение.

Как это сделать?

**main.py**

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Main Window")
        self.setFixedSize(645, 500)

    def button(self):
        # вот здесь мне надо изменить размер окна но у меня это не получается из-за метода setFixedSize

def application_setup():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application_setup()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: сделал, так нормально?

Comment: Али-Мухаммад Закарьяев
 А если вызвать ещё раз этот метод - self.setFixedSize с другими параметрами?

Comment: спасибо вам тоже, сработало

Comment: @Александр да, это один йз вариантов. Но плохо что нет объяснений зачем это надо сделать. Мне думается что нужен третий вариант.

Comment: S. Nick Нет пояснений от автора вопроса или от меня?) Не совсем понял, я то понимаю для чего нужен этот метод, а автору вопроса скорее всего необходим self.resize(a, b) или self.setGeometry(x, y, a, b)

Comment: Али-Мухаммад Закарьяев на мой взгляд вы неправильно используете этот метод, он скорее всего рассчитан на всю жизнь приложения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> void QWidget::[**setFixedSize**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#setFixedSize)(const `QSize` &s)
>
> Устанавливает минимальный и максимальный размеры виджета равными **`s`**, тем самым предотвращая его рост или уменьшение.
>
> Это переопределит ограничения размера по умолчанию, установленные `QLayout`.
>
> Чтобы удалить ограничения, установите размер `QWIDGETSIZE_MAX`.
>
> Альтернативно, если вы хотите, чтобы виджет имел фиксированный размер в зависимости от его содержимого, вы можете вызвать `QLayout::setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize)`;

```
import sys
#from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Main Window")
        self.setFixedSize(645, 500)
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setText('Update')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self._button)
        
        self.flag = True

    def _button(self):
        # вот здесь мне надо изменить размер окна но у меня это не получается 
        # из-за метода setFixedSize

        if self.flag:  
        
# или установите новое значение:         
#           self.setFixedSize(800, 300)

# или альтернативно, если вы хотите, чтобы виджет имел фиксированный размер 
# в зависимости от его содержимого, вы можете вызвать 
# QLayout::setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize): 
#           self.layout.setSizeConstraint(QLayout.SetFixedSize)
            
# или удалить ограничения, установите размер QWIDGETSIZE_MAX:  
            self.setFixedSize(16777215, 16777215)
            
        else:
            print(f'{self.size()}') #
            size = self.size()
# или установите новое значение: 
            self.setFixedSize(size)
        
        self.flag = not self.flag


def application_setup():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application_setup()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо огромное, как всегда помогли!

Comment: @Али-МухаммадЗакарьяев пожалуйста